# Python3. ImportError: no module named 'myfile'

Tags: python, macos, unix

```
iMac-Mark:~ Mark$ python3
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 13 2013, 13:52:24) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import myfile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'myfile'
```

I am new to Python and programming in general. I read a bit about `sys.path`, `__PATH__` but I didn't understand anything.

Comment: And you actually do have a `myfile.py` module?

Comment: Check if there is `myfile.py` in the working directory.

Comment: @falsetru Can you explain what is the "working" directory?

Comment: Have you `__init__.py` file near the `myfile.py`?

Comment: @itdxer Must or mustn't it be? I tried with and without it, no matter.

Comment: It must be near this file.

Comment: Please, can you show output from this command `ls -la ~ | grep myfile`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solutions:

1. Have you `__init__.py` file near the `myfile.py`?
2. Do you have you directory in `sys.path`? (if not add it like this sys.path.append('path/to/python/code'))
3. If you try import it from python enviroment you need run python shell near this file

Also you can try run this code

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

In your output you can see list of all directories which python see. If your file in any another directory you must change directory or python `sys.path`

You can do like this

```
$ python3
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/all/path/to/Desktop/Python')
>>> import myfile
```

Or like this

```
$ cd ~/Desktop/Python
$ python3
>>> import myfile
```

Comment: 1. Yes.
2. No. How do I need to add it, if its path is '~/Desktop/Python/myfile.py'?
3. From python environment? I don't understand you.

Comment: I'll try but how do I need to add it, if its path is '~/Desktop/Python/myfile.py'?